# How to add all active forms names to menustrip items in windows application C#

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I want to add all the active forms names to the toolstripmenuitem of MenuStrip in my windows application to know how many and which forms are in open state. If I close any form that perticuller name should delete from menustrip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property to get all the opened forms. Something like following.

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
{
    ms.Items.Add(form.Name);
}
```

Comment: `OpenForms` implements `IEnumerable`.. so it might be cleaner to remove the LINQ from the end and just iterate over the collection and add `form.Name`.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I am getting too much into LINQ, thanks for the tip :) modified my code

Comment: then how to close one item when perticuler form closed